# Is there a good library for an un-intrusive alternative to UIAlertView

Tags: iphone, ios

I was watching [session 105 - Polishing your app](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/). They recommended something like this to avoid disrupting the user's flow when errors are recoverable.

[image: Bottom alert view for network connection]

Is there a good library on GitHub for this?

Comment: Just add a label which is not visible until you want it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend searching the cocoacontrols site (it's effectively an iOS-focused front-end to github:-) for "notification" (e.g. using [this](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=notification) link).

From the list there, I personally use WPost and SVStatusHub

Comment: +1 for the CocoaControls reference. SVStatusHud is great. BTW, you can also search for "toast".

Answer (score 2):

You're over thinking it. Why do you need a library for this? You can create your own UIView subclass in 10 minutes that you can customise however you want.

Add the view just off the screen, animate in when there's an error, then animate out after, say, 5 seconds. Easy.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend <del>[TSMessages](https://github.com/toursprung/TSMessages)</del> [RMessage](https://github.com/donileo/RMessage). They look good and they're easy to use.

Comment: This one is good, but now abandoned.

Comment: @saswanb good point. I used RMessage (the one they recommend) and it worked well. I’ll update the answer I gave.

Answer (score 2):

I just finished a library called [ALAlertBanner](https://github.com/alobi/ALAlertBanner) that does this. If you're still in the market for this functionality, check it out and let me know your thoughts!

Comment: wow man this is great. I have an issue tho. If I present a view modally then show a banner. Once the view is dissmissed i cannot show the banner again. Im not sure if its a bug or an error on my part please advice

Comment: @Anthony any idea? i really wanted to use it

Comment: @meda does it happen in the demo project? If so, feel free to file in the issue tracker.

Comment: @Anthony no my own project. please advice

Comment: @meda I suggest you read over the documentation thoroughly - it has instructions on how to get things working properly.

Answer (score 1):

add a subview at bottom and increase it's frame when you dont want to display it and decrease when you want to show it using animations, some thing like this

```
//theAlert is a viewController whose nib is as what you desire
            [theAlert.view setFrame:CGRectMake( 0.0f, 0.0f, 480.0f, 50.0f)]; //notice this is OFF screen!and 480 as your view hieght is 480 and alert hieght 50 so it will not show on screen

            [UIView beginAnimations:@"animateToolbar" context:nil];
            [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.8];
            [theAlert.view setFrame:CGRectMake( 0.0f, 0.0f, 430.0f, 50.0f)]; //notice this is ON screen!

            [UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: +1 for rolling your own, -1 for old style **UIView beginAnimations**

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at YRDropdownView. I just came across it and it looks good.

https://github.com/onemightyroar/YRDropdownView